# Unable to compile FFmpeg for android on mac

Tags: android, mobile-application, ffmpegkit

I am trying to compile latest update of [ffmpeg-kit](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit.git) for android on my mac. But after running android.sh script, found the following errors:

```
jni/../ffmpeg-kit-android-lib/src/main/cpp/fftools_cmdutils.c:983:17: error: implicit declaration of function 'av_dict_iterate' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    while ((t = av_dict_iterate(opts, t))) {
                ^
jni/../ffmpeg-kit-android-lib/src/main/cpp/fftools_cmdutils.c:983:15: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'const AVDictionaryEntry *' (aka 'const struct AVDictionaryEntry *') from 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
    while ((t = av_dict_iterate(opts, t))) {
              ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
make: *** [/Users/mymac/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/core/build-binary.mk:422: obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ffmpegkit/fftools_cmdutils.o] Error 1
```

In ~/.zshrc file, I set this configuration:

```
PATH=/Users/mymac/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/mymac/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/mymac/Library/Android/sdk
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/Users/mymac/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config
source ~/.zshrc
```